# Stability of smoothness under base change

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I am studying Qing Liu’s “Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves” and am at a loss about the section on smooth morphisms.

I am trying to understand the stability of smooth morphisms under base change, ie Proposition 4.3.38.

In my text (I think it was elaborated on in later versions) the claim is supposed to “follow immediately”.

Let me recall the definitions: an algebraic variety $X$ over a field $k$ is smooth, if $X_{\overline{k}}$ has no singular point (ie if the dimension over the residue fields of the Zariski tangent spaces matches at each point the Krull dimension of the ring of stalks).

A morphism $f: X \rightarrow Y$ of finite type with $Y$ locally Noetherian is smooth if it is flat and if for each $y \in Y$, the base change of $f$ by $\operatorname{Spec}{k(y)} \rightarrow Y$ (which is the structural morphism of the algebraic variety $X_y$ over $k(y)$) is smooth.

So my goal is to prove that a base change of a smooth morphism is smooth. Flatness is easy to check, so the question becomes the following (with the base change being an extension of algebraically closed fields, but it implies the general case):

Let $V$ be a smooth algebraic variety over an algebraically closed field $K$. Let $L$ be an algebraically closed extension of $L$. Then $V_L$ is a smooth algebraic variety over $L$.

I can’t see anything to do, because there doesn’t seem to be an “obvious” way to transfer regularity from $V$ to $V_L$, since the dimension of the stalk rings is not even preserved.

So I would be very interested in any hints or sketches of proof (hopefully that do not rely on nontrivial results not mentioned at that point in the book).

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: Reduce to the affine case. You're over a field, so you can use the Jacobian criteria for smoothness which gives you that the nonsmooth points are exactly cut out by some ideal $I$. Now $V(I)$ is empty by assumption over an algebraically closed field. What does this tell you about $I$ via the Nullstellensatz?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We need however to assume that the variety is irreducible, so that the dimensions of stalk rings is the same everywhere, don’t we?

Comment: I don't see any need to do that - if two irreducible components meet at a point, then that point isn't smooth. Why do you think we need this?

Comment: I suppose I hadn’t fully realized that since regular local rings are integral domains, the connected components of Noetherian regular schemes are irreducible.

Comment: @KReiser I think you refer to Q. Liu's exercise 4.3.20 when you say "Jacobian criterion for smoothness". I have a concern about how to use this. Infact it works if the point we are considering is a closed point and, if we want to "transport regularity", shouldn't we know that also the image of this point is a closed one? (So that we are allowed to use the J. criterion)

Comment: @KReiser If what I mean is not so clear I'll open a different question with more details ;)